# What is the use of new operator in the following code?

Tags: java, class, object, linked-list, new-operator

I am new to Java. I have a been trying linked list using class but I encountered some problem.

```
class Node
{
  int data;
  Node next;
}
class LinkedListOperations
{
  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
  {
    Node element = new Node();
    Node head;
    .......
    .......
    .......
  }
}
```

As per my knowledge, the statement `Node element = new Node()` creates an object called element consisting of 2 fields namely next and data, but I am not sure what does `Node head` do?
What will be stored in `Node head`?
Will there be only `next` field or `data` field or both the fields?
Can someone explain using an example so that I can have a clear picture?

Comment: It declares a variable of type Node, named head. This variable will be null by default until assigned a value. Also, your question will likely soon be deleted as it's already been addressed. No big deal, just letting you know.

Comment: Will it have both the fields, data and next? If so, then what is the difference between  `Node element=new Node()` and `Node next`?